# display multiple rows by getting parameter value in access or excel-vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I need this in ACCESS or VB, below is the dummy table.

```
+------+-----------+-------+
|item  |  case_no  |  qty  |
+------+-----------+-------+
|laptop|    1      |   1   |
|laptop|    1      |   2   |
|laptop|    1      |   3   |
|laptop|    1      |   4   |
|laptop|    1      |   5   |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

Parameters: item, case_no, qty

For example:

`if item=laptop, case=1 and qty=5` then return only one row

```
+-------+---------+-------+
|Item   | case_no | qty   |
+-------+---------+-------+
|Laptop |   1     |  5    |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

`If item=laptop, case=1 and qty=6` then return only that rows which qty equal to 6 and if qty asked not equal to exact numbers then take one full qty and remaining from other.

```
+-------+---------+------+
| Item  | case_no | qty  |
+-------+---------+------+
|Laptop |    1    |   1  |
|Laptop |    1    |   5  |
+-------+---------+------+
```

Comment: Why `qty 1,5` and not `qry 2,4` ?

Comment: There's never a good reason to tag your question both VBA and VB.NET.  It's either one or the other.  Which is yours?

Comment: No problem, it's also correct, i mention 1,5 just for example.

Answer (score 0):

First post here, hope I don't mess it up.

If you're looking for up to two rows (not more than two), I think this does it. Made it on Access 2013 - VBA.

It assumes data stored in table "table_stack" with structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_stack (item TEXT, case_nr DOUBLE, qty DOUBLE)
```

"qty" column content must be by ascending order (as per your example).

To call the sub, use, for instance:

```
Call get_up_to_two_rows("laptop", 1, 7)
```

### **Main CODE:**

```
Sub get_up_to_two_rows(input_item As String, input_case_nr As Integer, input_qty As Integer)
    Dim rs, rs2 As dao.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("table_stack") 'must be ordered by qty ASC !!!

    'looks for an exact match of the requested parameters:
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If ((rs!item = input_item) And (rs!case_nr = input_case_nr) And (rs!qty = input_qty)) Then
            'exports row with match into new table called "result_table":
            DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO result_table FROM table_stack WHERE (table_stack.[item] = '" & input_item & "' AND table_stack.[case_nr] = " & input_case_nr & " AND table_stack.[qty] = " & input_qty & ")"
            GoTo end_sub_code 'cleanup code before End Sub
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'If it doesn't find exact match, will look for a pair of rows where the sum of them will match desired qty:

    '"opens" (as recordset) a table with a single row containing all the qty for the other parameters, from highest qty to lowest
    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT qty FROM table_stack WHERE (table_stack.[item] = '" & input_item & "' AND table_stack.[case_nr] = " & input_case_nr & ") ORDER BY qty DESC")

    'For each qty in list of qtys (beginning with highest)
    rs2.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs2.EOF
        upper_quantity = rs2!qty 'takes current qty value
        target_qty = input_qty - upper_quantity 'takes qty needed to meet "input_qty = current_qty + needed_qty"

        'looks for that value in the table:
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            If ((rs!item = input_item) And (rs!case_nr = input_case_nr) And (rs!qty = target_qty)) Then

                'If it finds that value, stores both corresponding rows in result table:
                DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO result_table FROM table_stack WHERE (table_stack.[item] = '" & input_item & "' AND table_stack.[case_nr] = " & input_case_nr & " AND table_stack.[qty] = " & rs!qty & ")"
                DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO result_table SELECT * FROM table_stack WHERE (table_stack.[item] = '" & input_item & "' AND table_stack.[case_nr] = " & input_case_nr & " AND table_stack.[qty] = " & upper_quantity & ")"

                GoTo end_sub_code
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

        rs2.MoveNext
    Loop

    'If it doesn't find a pair of rows to meet desired qty, it sends out this message:
    MsgBox "Couldn't find two rows in table 'table_stack' to meet requested qty."

end_sub_code:
    rs.Close
    rs2.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it is not fix that result shows only two rows. if quantity is big then it will go more rows, until quantity that need.

Comment: @Ahsan : oh, I see. I've been a bit busy lately, but will try to do that when I get the chance.